# Rascal Using the webserver module

Tags: rascal

I'm currently working on the stable version of Rascal and I want to spawn the Rascal webserver to serve my html templates with javascript functions.
Looking at the Webserver module I can't see how to use the serve function to use the webserver. It asks for a location (I'm assuming that the location would be something like `|http://localhost:8080|`) and a callback that has the type of `Response (Request)` but what is that type? I don't know how to create this kind of type and what it exactly is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type

```
Response (Request) callback
```

is a function, E.g.:

```
Response (Request r) { 
    return response(...);
}
```

This function is an anonymous function (it has no name) that you can pass into the serve function as an argument, you can also define it as a normal function with a name, and just put the name of that function as the argument.

So this would probably work:

```
serve(|http://localhost:8080|, 
           Response (Request r){ 
               return response("Hello world"); 
           }):
```

Since there is a factory method

```
Response response(str content)
```

in Webserver.rsc, that will create a response for you from a string argument.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of documentation about this module, all you can do is read the source. In the Eclipse browser, the libraries are accessible (indicated by little jar icons) and you'll find `util::Webserver` there with the definition of the `Response` and `Request` types.

Basically `Request` is a callback function with all the HTTP headers and stuff as parameters and `Response` is a wrapper with alternative response types (files, strings, etc.).

Note that the current version is quite a bit different from the stable version you use, so reading code on github will not help much.

Comment: I have noticed that implementations present on github like the one for TutorWebserver use a ```dispatchserver``` that is nowhere present in the stable. The source code of Webserver does not really state that a datatype followed by parenthesis is an anonymous function which brought my confusion. I did not expect that Rascal had anonymous functions.